# HTML link style tag from one fileto another

Tags: html, css

I'm new with HTML and I'm having problems with my style tag. I created one but I don't know if I have to copy/paste it in every html file I use or if I can just link that tag from the index file into other files and if so how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best solution is to create an external style sheet, name it styles.css, put it in the same folder like your index.html for the beginning and link it in the head of your html tag, like this:

[image]

Add classes to your html tags like this:
[image]

and then you can add the propertys to your external style sheet and reuse them in other html tags, if you want the same style of course.

[image]